# Reexporting the CommonModule is required when we import BrowserModule at app start?

Tags: angular

I was trying to understand the `shared module` in angular, I have seen examples like this

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({imports:[CommonModule], exports:[CommonModule]})
export class SharedModule{}
```

We are importing the CommonModule and exporting the CommonModule, so that we dont need to import the CommonModule but we are importing the `BrowserModule` at app start and it imports the `CommonModule. Is it neccessary to reexport the CommonModule? Please also kindly explain what exactly the shared module is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared module is basically the module that gathers all declarations used in other modules and exports them. For example you have `AComponent` in `A` module and `BComponent` in `B` module. You want to use them in module `C`. So you have to do like this:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ModuleA, ModuleB]
   ...
})
export class ModuleC {}
```

However, you could gather those in some shared module:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ModuleA, ModuleB],
   exports: [ModuleA, ModuleB]
   ...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And then simply import `SharedModule`:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [SharedModule]
   ...
})
export class ModuleC {}
```

You import it so that components declared in the shared module can use `CommonModule` declarations. If you don't have any declarations defined on the `SharedModule`, you can simply export `CommonModule` without importing it.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [], // don't need to import if modules doesn't have declarations
   exports: [ModuleA, ModuleB]
   ...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

> but we are importing the BrowserModule at app start and it imports the
>   `CommonModule

It's enough to import the module that imports the required module once. **However**, you need to import the module with declarations **into every module** that uses declarations from other modules. So even though you imported `BrowserModule` into `AppModule`, you still need to import `CommonModule` to other modules that use common declarations (components, directives and pipes). So you don't import `BrowserModule` into those modules, you import `SharedModule`