# BrowserModule is exporting CommonModule without importing

Tags: angular

I was checking the Angular 17 source code from https://github.com/angular/angular

I am confused how the BrowserModule is written. Look at the below code.

[image]

As you can see BrowserModule is exporting CommonModule without importing it in the first place. How is that possible? can someone explain?

Answer (score -1):

In the `@NgModule`, the `exports` property specifies what should be made available to other modules that import `BrowserModule`.

So, any module that imports `BrowserModule` indirectly gets access to all the exported features of
`CommonModule`.

If you were to import `BrowserModule`, for example, in your `AppModule`, it would get access to all the features provided by `CommonModule` without having to explicitly import it.

This is called **re-exporting**.

It also mentions it [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule).

And you could also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223496/reexporting-the-commonmodule-is-required-when-we-import-browsermodule-at-app-sta) SO question useful.

But, you might be wondering... would it cause an error to import `CommonModule` in the `BrowserModule`?

The answer is **no** but it would be **redundant**. Your program would still work correctly but there is no reason to do this. Importing it explicitly doesn't provide any additional benefits. The exported features of `CommonModule` are already available to any module that imports `BrowserModule`, as I mentioned.

Angular's is designed to handle dependencies and exports in a way that minimizes redundancy. The idea is to create reusable code so unnecessary imports should be avoided for cleaner and more maintainable code.